# How to increase the speed of loading the localhost?

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have view table. My view table query is like this

```
select DISTINCT `TahunAwal`, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `< 2.50` from `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` 
        LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswamagister` on `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`MahasiswaID` = `akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MahasiswaID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdhis_statusmahasiswa` on `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`MahasiswaID` = `akdhis_statusmahasiswa`.`MahasiswaID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdref_tahunsemester` on `akdhis_statusmahasiswa`.`TahunSemesterID` = `akdref_tahunsemester`.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdref_tahunakademik` on `akdref_tahunsemester`.`TahunAkademikID` = `akdref_tahunakademik`.`ID`
        WHERE `IPK` < 2.50 AND `SemesterMahasiswa` = 8 AND `mhsMagister`.`TahunAwal`=`akdref_tahunakademik`.`TahunAwal`) AS `< 2.50`,

    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `2.50-2.74` from `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi` 
        LEFT JOIN `akdmst_mahasiswamagister` on `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`MahasiswaID` = `akdmst_mahasiswamagister`.`MahasiswaID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdhis_statusmahasiswa` on `akdhis_kelanjutanstudi`.`MahasiswaID` = `akdhis_statusmahasiswa`.`MahasiswaID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdref_tahunsemester` on `akdhis_statusmahasiswa`.`TahunSemesterID` = `akdref_tahunsemester`.`ID`
        LEFT JOIN `akdref_tahunakademik` on `akdref_tahunsemester`.`TahunAkademikID` = `akdref_tahunakademik`.`ID`
        WHERE 2.50 < `IPK` < 2.74 AND `SemesterMahasiswa` = 8 AND `mhsMagister`.`TahunAwal`=`akdref_tahunakademik`.`TahunAwal`) AS `2.50-2.74`                
from `akdref_tahunakademik` AS `mhsMagister` 
ORDER BY `mhsMagister`.`TahunAwal`
```

that's a part of my codes

and the result in phpmyadmin is like this

[image]

my problem is that localhost takes a long time to load data. I think, it is because of the tables that consists of many data records.

I change

ServerName Localhost to ServerName 127.0.0.1:80.

I also have edited

my.ini.

I uncommented

```
bind-address="127.0.0.1"
```

I edited

config.inc.php

I change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost' to $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'
```

but localhost still too slow.

I'm using XAMPP in windows 7.

is there any way to fix that problem? Thank you

Comment: *is there any way to fix that problem?* what is the problem ?

Comment: my problem is : localhost takes long time to load data @Ravi

Comment: I have edited my question @Ravi

Comment: what do you mean by slow. You can try restarting your laptop/desktop. You can try restarting `Apache` server